# Playstation Emulation

Tags: debian, driver, emulation

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the PCSXR (Playstation 1) emulator to work on the Raspberry Pi? On both Debian Squeeze and Wheezy, running any game on it with the xvideo plugin just gives.

> RGB & YUV not found.  Quitting.

I presume this is something to do with the proprietary driver / firmware not working with xvideo. The only other plugin is OpenGL (not es though), so i don't think that will work. Has anyone been able to get this to work on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It might take a while before that even gets to working level. THe problem is that the emulator depends heavily on CPU and GPU translations(emulation) The raspberry might not be capabale of this unless a RPI specific (or openGL) version is ported.. lots of work

Comment: Have you tried OpenGL anyway?  If the emulator works with XVideo or OpenGL, it's probably just drawing on an OpenGL texture rather than using any advanced features (because those features won't be available in XVideo mode.)  Since this is a pretty basic use of OpenGL, the ES version shouldn't have a problem with it.

Answer (score 7):

[PCSX-ReARMed](http://notaz.gp2x.de/pcsx_rearmed.php) should be already runnable on the Raspberry Pi. In [this thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=13349) people says that it compiles fine but it's a little bit slow, still playable though.

Here a couple of youtube videos that show the smoothness of two games: [Crash Bandicoot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQDt_Ijj11U) and [Dragon Ball GT Final Bout](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASmCLkpGdQg).

As someone already said, now the Raspberry Pi is the cheapest Playstation console ever! :)

Comment: Awesome. Putting a heat sink on and over clocking might help a bit :)

Comment: The videos are now dead :(

Answer (score 0):

On desktop Ubuntu the fix for the same error is under the Configuration Menu, select Plugins & BIOS then change the Graphics dropdown from 
XVideo Driver" to "OpenGL Driver".

[I wrote about this and another error that often comes afterwards here](http://blog.ryanhalliday.com/2018/02/pcsxr-errors.html)